# Build and deploy asp.net MVC WCF application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build-process

I am fairly new to creating deployments for projects. 
I have a asp.net MVC web application and WCF service layer (5 services).
Our QA team needs to get latest build packages to test the application.
At the moment we have command line build scripts which gets the latest source, build with the Visual Studio and copy those build outputs to IIS and Services folder(Services are hosted as Windows services).

What would be the recommended way to do this? We have TFS builds, but we are not using those build outputs at the moment. 
What would be the recommended way to set up a deployment for these projects?

Answer (score 0):

You should automate your deployment pipeline.
You can use TFS builds in conjunction with [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) or with [Octopus](http://octopusdeploy.com/) to achieve this goal.